# Reading an Excel File with Embedded Word Documents in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, ms-word

So right now my ASP.net app is working great, I am able to read the Excel file nothing fancy here:

```
      string conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Sample.xls;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes\"";
      string SQLString = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
      OleDbConnection DBConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
      OleDbCommand DBCommand = new OleDbCommand(sQuery, DBConnection);
      IDataReader iReader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

After this I can display the spreadsheet on a DataGrid object and most of the cells look fine.

However, this spreadsheet contains embedded word documents in some of the cells. For example, if I highlight the cell I see "=EMBED("Word.Document.8","")" and there is a word document there in the cell.

So my question is does anyone know how I can access these embedded word documents? Right now the cells just show up as empty on my DataGrid.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will be able to do this with OLEDB.  You will have to rely on COM Interop to get the data out.  Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597926.aspx

Comment: And proper using  MS Office COM Interop on the server side of ASP.NET is not easy. Loading Excel means consuming lots of resources, be carefull.